# What is the meaning of this line in the below code?

Tags: python, flask

What is the meaning of this line("app = Flask(**name**)") in the below code?

I am aware that **name** is a special variable that gets as value the string "**main**" when we are executing the script. Please tell me why we are passing **name** here in "app = Flask(**name**)"?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
   return "Hey there!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What do you *think* the answer is?

Comment: Read top to bottom. That is how the code is read by the interpreter. Though since that is flask `home()` will run when you go on the website to the main page for example `127.0.0.1/`

Answer (score -1):

Flask is a class datatype, or in simpler words, it is used to create instances of web applications. The **name** part is a variable that gets the string **main**. The lines would be called in the following order: line 1 (the import) then defining app, then just work your way down the line like that
Also, check this website out for more information.

https://pythonhow.com/how-a-flask-app-works/